# XY Graph from two time signals

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, cross-correlation

I have two measurement signals (let's say a voltage signal and a current signals), both with timestamps and corresponding values.
The timestamps of the two signals doesn't match up and aren't evenly spaced.

I have to plot a XY graph, where the x-axis is voltage and the y-axis is current.

How can I correlate the two signals? Is there maybe a ready to use Octave/MatLab/Scilab/numpy function?

Comment: How was the experiment performed? How far off are the time signals?

Comment: The signals are send from different measurement devices (multimeters, power supplies, ...) with different measurement intervals for each device. The intervals for the different devices are between 100ms and 1s.

Comment: Is this a homework problem or an experiment you've done yourself?

Comment: It is for an open source software I'm writing: https://github.com/knarfS/smuview

Comment: If you were to first curve fit voltage versus time, and then current versus time, you could find the voltage and current values for the same time value from these fitted curves. If the fitted curves matched the data well, this might be a reasonable approach.

Comment: You have two sets of data, $(t,x)_i$ and $(t,y)_i$ and wish to estimate a function $(x(t),y(t)).$ A standard way is to interpolate each set separately (*e.g.*, spline them).  Interpolation is a huge subject.  Among other things, it teaches us that underlying theory, previous experience, and your analytical objectives are important factors in determining how to perform the interpolation. To the extent you can supply such relevant information, the answers you get will be better and more useful.

Comment: If you're expecting a reading from each but their separation in time isn't standard I would just rank them by time - the first voltage goes with the first current etc but I would recommend setting up your data collection differently - it doesn't sound very well suited to the problem.